# Python: How to save and extract scores and data on an external file and sort them into highscores

Tags: python, file, comparison

So for many pieces of code I've looked at making for beginning my CS education is figuring out how to save and read high scores on an external file.
I know how to write and read on an external text file in a basic way but that's it - I don't know how to extract it as an integer or sort the data.

Please can someone help me in telling me what external file i should use or some code i can use to extract/sort data as an integer?
(Note this is my first post so please forgive my failure or formatting)

```
score = dice1 + dice2
highscorefile = open('highscores.txt','r')
cont = highscorefile.read()
file.close()
```

I need some form of way that i can then compare score to the contents in the file because text files obviously aren't for storing and comparing integers.

All replies appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your file content, it makes a huge difference in this question, we need to know how these numbers are separated or aligned for the computer to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample:

**highscores.txt**

```
1,2
5,5
6,2
4,3
5,2
```

```
# we are creating a file handle here inorder to read file.
highscorefile = open('highscores.txt','r') 
# We are reading the file contents using the read function
cont = highscorefile.read() 
# we are splitting the read content line by line and \n represents new lines here
for line in cont.split('\n'):
# we are again splitting the line by commas and address first item for dice1, second time for dice two and converting them to integers and addressing for the sum
  print(" dice1 : ",line.split(',')[0]," dice2 : ",line.split(',')[1]," sum : ",int(line.split(',')[0]) + int(line.split(',')[2])
#After completing this operations we are closing the file.
highscorefile.close()
```